# Universal property for rings of fractions

Tags: abstract-algebra, universal-property

Let $R$ denote a (commutative and unital) ring and $S\subset R$ a multiplicative subset. Let $S^{-1}R$ denote the **ring of fractions**. I now want to consider the canonical projection $\pi: R\rightarrow S^{-1}R, r\mapsto \frac{r}{1}$. We are now supposed to show in our homework that $\pi$ is well-defined and for $s\in S: \pi(s)\in (S^{-1}R)^{*}$.

For well-definedness: Let $r=r'$, then $\pi(r) = \frac{r}{1}$ and $\pi(r') = \frac{r'}{1}$. Since $r=r'\Rightarrow \pi(r)=\pi(r')$. Is this short proof correct for well-definedness?

For $\pi(s)\in (S^{-1}R)^{*}$: I found in Grillet's Book (GTM), "Abstract Algebra", that the inverse is supposed to be $\frac{1}{s}$. Alright, but why doesn't this construction hold for all $r\in R$? I mean that $R$ itself is a multiplicative subset, i.e., $\forall a, b\in R: ab\in R$.

EDIT: @Don Thousand, alright, I see your point. $\frac{r}{1}$ is defined as the set $\{(\tilde r, \tilde s)\in R\times S \mid \exists u\in S: r\tilde su = \tilde r \cdot 1\cdot u = \tilde r u\}$. We also know that $\frac{r'}{1} = \{(\tilde r, \tilde s) \in R\times S\mid \exists u\in S: r' \tilde s u = \tilde r \cdot  1 \cdot u = \tilde r u \} \Rightarrow \frac{r}{1} = \frac{r'}{1}$. This is how I would have proved the well-definedness.

Kind regards, 
MathIsFun

Comment: For the well-defined proof, you need to show that $$\frac r1=\frac {r'}1$$which is pretty trivial to do, but I would be more explicit than what you've done.

Comment: Secondly, elements of $S^{-1}R$ are elements of the form $\frac rs$, where $r\in R$, $s\in S$. Since $1\in R$, that implies that $\frac 1s$ is in $S^{-1}R$. But, what fraction of this form gets you $\frac1r$?

Comment: I don't actually see why we need to check $\pi$ is well-defined. There is no assumed ambiguity in representing elements in the domain $R$ of $\pi$, and the fact there is ambiguity in representing the elements of the codomain $S^{-1}R$ is irrelevant (unless one wanted to show the function is one-to-one?)